# Fluent NHibernate mapping properties coming from an interface in one place

Tags: c#, interface, fluent-nhibernate

If many classes implement the same interface(s), is it possible to map those interface properties in one place? There's more code @ [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/UEDeKceA)

You can see here that classes have some common interfaces (but not all to make common base class) and I had to repeat mappings.

```
public class PostMapping : SubclassMap<Post>
{
    public PostMapping()
    {
        Map(x => x.Text, "Text");
        // coming from IMultiCategorizedPage
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Categories).Table("PageCategories").ParentKeyColumn("PageId").ChildKeyColumn("CategoryId").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
        // coming from IMultiTaggedPage
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Tags).Table("PageTags").ParentKeyColumn("PageId").ChildKeyColumn("TagId").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
        // coming from ISearchablePage
        Map(x => ((ISearchablePage)x).SearchIndex, "SearchIndex").LazyLoad();
    }
}
public class ArticleMapping : SubclassMap<Article>
{
    public ArticleMapping()
    {
        Map(x => x.Text, "Text");
        // coming from ISingleCategorizedPage
        References(x => x.Category, "CategoryId");
        // coming from IMultiTaggedPage
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Tags).Table("PageTags").ParentKeyColumn("PageId").ChildKeyColumn("TagId").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
        // coming from ISearchablePage
        Map(x => ((ISearchablePage)x).SearchIndex, "SearchIndex").LazyLoad();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If C# had complete multiple inheritance instead of just multiple interface inheritance then this would be easy. It seems the closest would be creating a single wrapping interface for a mapping base class to hold your common elements. Then, you could create table specific mapping classes that inherit from it. Something along the lines of this code:

```
public class BasePageMapping : SubclassMap<IPage> //IPage could inherit: IMultiTaggedPage, ISearchablePage
{
    public BasePageMapping()
    {
        Map(x => x.Text, "Text");
        // coming from IMultiTaggedPage
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Tags).Table("PageTags").ParentKeyColumn("PageId").ChildKeyColumn("TagId").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
        // coming from ISearchablePage
        Map(x => ((ISearchablePage)x).SearchIndex, "SearchIndex").LazyLoad();
    }
}

public class PostMapping : BasePageMapping
{
    public PostMapping()  // don't need to specify : base() because it happens automatically
    {
        Table("the specific table");

        HasManyToMany(x => x.Categories).Table("PageCategories").ParentKeyColumn("PageId").ChildKeyColumn("CategoryId").Cascade.SaveUpdate();

        //Other table specific mappings:
    }
}
```